# Issue with Juniper vMX14 route reflector not transmitting VRF

Tags: router, reflector, bgp, juniper, mpls

I am working on a project implementing Seamless MPLS on a Juniper vMX14 router. I have configured all the necessary configurations for MPLS routing, but I am having an issue with the route reflector. The route reflector doesn't seem to be working properly as it is neither receiving nor transmitting the VRF. The MP-BGP protocol works correctly before the use of the route reflector as the VRFs are transmitted between the BGP neighbors and the "#show bgp summary" command gives me the "established" state.

Here are the configurations I have implemented for the route reflector:

```
set protocols bgp group ibgp type internal

set protocols bgp group ibgp local-address 6.6.6.6

set protocols bgp group ibgp family inet-vpn unicast

set protocols bgp group ibgp family route-target

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 1.1.1.1 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 3.3.3.3 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 10.10.10.10 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 11.11.11.11 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 2.2.2.2 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 4.4.4.4 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 5.5.5.5 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 7.7.7.7 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 8.8.8.8 peer-as 10

set protocols bgp group ibgp neighbor 9.9.9.9 peer-as 10
```

I have checked the configurations multiple times, and I am sure they are correct. However, I am unable to understand why the route reflector is not working.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this issue? Or could anyone provide me with advice on debugging this situation? Also, is there a special command that identifies the route reflector on the vMX14?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To configure a RR on Junos, the "set protocols bgp group ibgp cluster x.x.x.x"  is required.  Juniper's better philosophy, in contrast to cisco's, requires you to manually configure parameters such as this, as opposed to relying on obscure, error-prone, overly complex, and ever changing election procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `"set protocols bgp cluster <cluster-id>"` under the protocol bgp ....also no need to set peer-as as its ibgp